# Child Div same size as parent Div 100% (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css, resize

I want to have two `div`s with 100% height.

The parent `div` should be filled with an image and become auto-sized.

The child `div` should be like a color filter. It must have the parent's `div` size when the hole page is resized.

I found a few ways on the Internet with the same problem as my solution: while resizing the page the child `div` is getting bigger or smaller than the parent `div`.

```
.main_slide_back {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
    width: calc(100% + 16px);
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.main_slide_back:after {
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #08598D;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.main_slide_back img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5256mucc/)

Thanks in advance.
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Just add relative position to ancestor. [Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5256mucc/2/).

```
.main_slide_back {
    position: relative;
}
```